# To enable Require secure connections (HTTPS) for all third-party domains

Tags: integration, security

I have to increase the security level of my org. I know that if I activate "Require Secure Connections (https) for all third-party domains" I may have problems with pre-existing integrations. How can I find out the list of all connections to make sure I do not cause problems? Could there be other problems?

thanks

Comment: Have you been brave enough to activate it? What happened?